# how can I replace System.Net.IPAddress.Any in .Net Core and listnen to all network adapters

Tags: c#, uwp, .net-core, network-programming

I am trying to port a VB .net project from .net framework into .net core and the new Windows universal platform apps.

In the network code the usage of .IPAddress.Any is frequent in order to be able to listnen to all networkadapters. Do anyone know of a way in .net core that I can use the DatagramSockets to listen to all networkadapters?

Answer (score 2):

`IPAddress.Any` is equivalent to `IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0")`

#### Using Windows.Networking.Sockets.DatagramSocket (Windows 8+)

```
private void Foo()
{
    datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket();
    datagramSocket.MessageReceived += OnMessageReceived;
    await datagramSocket.BindServiceNameAsync("8081");
}

private void OnMessageReceived(
    DatagramSocket sender,
    DatagramSocketMessageReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    // ...
}
```

#### Using System.Net.Sockets.Socket (.NET Core and UWP)

```
private void Foo()
{
    Socket udpSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);

    IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8081);

    udpSocket.Bind(remoteEndPoint);

    SocketAsyncEventArgs e = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    e.SetBuffer(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    e.RemoteEndPoint = remoteEndPoint;
    e.Completed += ReceiveFromCallback;

    if (!udpSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(e))
    {
        ReceiveFromCallback(udpSocket, e);
    }
}

private void ReceiveFromCallback(object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.SocketError != SocketError.Success)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(e.SocketError);
        return;
    }

    Socket udpSocket = sender as Socket;

    byte[] buffer = e.Buffer;
    Debug.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, e.BytesTransferred));

    if (!udpSocket.ReceiveFromAsync(e))
    {
        ReceiveFromCallback(udpSocket, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: does that mean that when I want to create my new data socket I can create it with: 
datagramSocket dg = new DataGramSocket();
dg.BindEndpointAsync(new Hostname("0.0.0.0", serverPort);

Comment: My understanding is that `DatagramSocket` is not part of .NET Core. Anyway, I have updated my answer with samples, take a look.

Comment: well, since I started developing windows UWP apps I must say that I find the msdn documentation very confusing and har to navigate. But from my point of view it looks like Datagramsockets are available in .Net core and UWP apps. I have used them both in c# and VB on raspberry PI:s. but I am not able to use the System.Net.Sockets.Socket namespace. when I search the msdn it says that it is a part of .Net framework which is different from .Net core. confusing enought .Net core is not a part of .Net framework